# Change date format while loading with LOAD IN DATA FILE

Tags: mysql

i am loading data from CSV file,it contains around 70k records ,in  csv file date format for one column is like 10/24/2013 5:27:05 PM and in my table date formate is like(datetime 00-00-0000) ,so when i am uploading data form csv file using below command it was failed due to different time stamp.

LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/fulldata.csv"  INTO TABLE test.customerorders COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

how can fix this time stamp in my table and how can i upload data in to the table?

Comment: use the `date_format` function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: if you want to store to datetime field you better use `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` format. works for all locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the data like following:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '10/24/2013 5:27:05 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p' )`

and store it in a datetime field

**edit**:
LOAD data file can load pretty faster for 70K records.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/filelocationfromroot' INTO TABLE `yourtablename` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(
`tablefieldforfirstcsvcolumn`,`tablefieldforsecondcsvcolumn`,...,@yourdatecolumn,
)
SET `datacolumnname`=STR_TO_DATE( @yourdatecolumn, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p' )
```

Comment: actually i am loading data from CSV file,it contains around 70k records ,in  csv file date formate is like 10/24/2013 5:27:05 PM and in my table date formate is like(datetime) so how can fix it and how can i upload it.

Comment: Thanks it is awe some